# How to solve authorizer issue in Serverless framework 3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

When I use Serverless framework 2, I defined authorizer like the below way.

```
sample:
  handler: sample.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: sample
        method: get
        cors: true
        authorizer: verify-token
```

But It's not supported in Serverless framework 3. Now, I am getting the below error.

```
Incorrect type. Expected "Aws.HttpAuthorizer".yaml-schema: Serverless Framework Configuration
```

I looked at their deprecated [doc](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations#default-identitysource-for-httpauthorizer) But I don't find the solution. How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Still no improvements ?

Comment: I didn't check recently.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like serverless expects you to define HttpAuthorizer instead of Lambda Authorizer for AWS REST API

Definitions of the settings are here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lalcebo/json-schema/master/serverless/reference.json

Rest API (V1) is actually more advanced. see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ApiGateway.html or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ApiGatewayV2.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Check the following documentation: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers

The authorizer declaration must be completed in v3:

```
sample:
  handler: sample.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: sample
        method: get
        cors: true
        authorizer:
          arn: xxx:xxx:verify-token
          managedExternally: false
          resultTtlInSeconds: 0
          identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
          identityValidationExpression: someRegex
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33523187)